# .then uncaught in promise this is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
sayHello() {
    this.startTSOAddressSpace().then(this.startApplication);
    return "filler";
}

post(contentURL: string) {
    let result = fetch(contentURL, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("An error occoured: " + e);
        });
    return result;
}

servletKey(result: any) {
    return result.servletKey;
}

startApplication(result: any) {
    console.log(this.servletKey(result));
    let contentURL = `${this.BASE_URL}/tsoAp/app/${this.servletKey(result)}`;
    console.log(contentURL);
    return this.post(contentURL);
}
```

When I run this code I am getting ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this is undefined. This happens when running the ".then(this.startApplication)"

Comment: When you do `this.startTSOAddressSpace().then(this.startApplication);`, the `then` method will invoke `startApplication()` (i.e. as a function) instead of `this.startApplication()` (as a method), so the function loses its `this` context. The answer by @NitishNarang should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing code below and see if it helps

from

```
sayHello() {
    this.startTSOAddressSpace().then(this.startApplication);
    return "filler";
}
```

to

```
sayHello() {
    this.startTSOAddressSpace().then(d => this.startApplication(d));
    return "filler";
}
```

Comment: are you still getting Same error? And is this because of "this.startApplication(d)" or somewhere else?

Comment: Ignore what I said before it Worked!